# Apache is downloading php files instead of displaying them

Tags: php, apache, centos

OS and server information:

- CentOS 6.4 (Final)
- Apache 2.2.15
- PHP 5.5.1

I previously had php 5.3.x installed but decided to upgrade. I first uninstalled the php 5.3.x and then installed php 5.5.1 but after the installation completed apache did not parse the php files it just downloaded them. I have checked similar questions here in stackoverflow but none of them have helped me so far.

For the record I have the following lines in my httpd.conf and php.conf that should make php work but don't:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php5 .php4 .php .php3 .php2 .phtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php5 .php4 .php .php3 .php2 .phtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

I would really appreciate any help.
Thank you.

EDIT:

I have these lines in the php.conf

```
<IfModule !worker.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so
</IfModule>
```

EDIT:

By removing the

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php5 .php4 .php .php3 .php2 .phtml
```

apache no longer downloads the file. Now apache is showing the source code, but not all of it just part. I added

```
AddType text/html .php
```

but no luck.

Comment: Well, *how* did you install it? Which SAPI? See also [How to check which apache modules are enabled/installed?](http://superuser.com/q/284898)

Comment: Your php module is not running.

Comment: check your `httpd.conf` if php module is commented or not

Comment: I edited the questions. The modules do exits and they are being loaded apparently

Comment: Did you restart apache after installation?

Comment: Yes I did. httpd restart

Comment: why not also upgrade apache to 2.4

Comment: and also try to see status of php mod and other things in mod_info and mod_status localhost/server-info

Comment: How can I update to apache 2.4 in centos? Do I have to uninstall the current apache installation?

Comment: Any idea how to solve this issue on client side (in browser) without access to server? Apparently, our company proxy may be involved in the issue (because it happens with wikipedia pages which open well outside of the office).

Comment: Where is httpd.conf ? Could you post the full path?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The correct AddType for php is application/x-httpd-php

```
AddType  application/x-httpd-php         .php
AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps
```

Also make sure your php module is loaded

```
LoadModule php5_module        modules/mod_php55.so
```

When you're configuring apache then try to view the page from another browser - I've had days when chrome stubbornly caches the result and it keeps downloading the source code while in another browser it's just fine.

Comment: there is no modules path in my case

Comment: Could you add some info where to put these lines?

Comment: For people looking for where to put these lines.

`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Comment: In my case , on Apache-2.4.6+PHP-7.3.13
>  LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so

Comment: This works, adding `d` part to `x-http-php` like on your post works ! I've configured php from source

Comment: For Debian put those lines in: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Answer (score 29):

I came across this issue today and none of the solutions described worked for me. So here is another possible cause:

If you have something like

```
AddHandler x-mapp-php6 .php3 .php4 .php .phtml
```

in a `.htaccess` file of your web content folder, it can cause your PHP scripts to stop working. In my case the server did not know the `x-mapp-php6` type, since that `.htaccess` file was something I imported from a different web host when I transferred the website content.

Just removing the `AddHandler` line from the `.htaccess` file solved it for me.

Comment: Perfect. In my case, it was `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54  .php54 .php` that had to be removed.

Comment: I had the some problem but found the culprit .htaccess file in the home directory (one directory above the "public_html" web directory). If anyone else has the same issue, look for .htaccess in parent directories also (the settings cascade).

Comment: I had an .htaccess file like this I had pulled from a web hosting server. It was forcing a version of PHP that was not installed on my local machine. Thus the virtual host wasn't executing the PHP file properly.

Comment: This is almost certainly the problem if some sites work and others don't.  Joomla .htaccess contained a AddHandler but WordPress didn't.

Comment: This worked for me, just removed that line from my public/.htaccess file and index was loaded.

Comment: This works for me by just removed that AddHandler line from .htaccess file

Answer (score 17):

After struggling a lot I finally solved the problem.

If you are prompted to download a `.php` file instead of executing it, then here is the perfect solution: I assume that you have installed PHP5 already and still getting this error.

```
$ sudo su
$ a2enmod php5
```

This is it.

But If you are still getting the error :

```
Config file php5.conf not properly enabled: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf is a real file, not touching it
```

then do the following:

Turns out files shouldn't be stored in `mods-enabled`, but should rather be stored in `mods-available`. A symlink should then be created in mods-enabled pointing to the file stored in mods-available.

First remove the original:

```
$ mv /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf /etc/apache2/mods-available/
```

Then create the symbolic link:

```
$ ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf
```

I hope your problem is solved.

Comment: Note that this only works under Linux (and specifically Debian Linux).

Answer (score 7):

Please take a look at your addtype directives.

It looks to me like Apache is telling the browser that it's sending a document type of application/php for scripts with extensions like .php5. In fact Apache is supposed to tell the browser that the script is outputting text/html.

Please try this:

```
AddType text/html .php
```

Regarding the suggestion above that you should tell the browser that you are outputting a PHP script: It seemed like an unusual idea to me. I googled it and found that there is quite a bit of discussion about it on the web. Apparently there are cases where you might want to say that you are sending a PHP script (even though Apache is supposed to execute the script and emit text/html,) and there are also cases where the browser simply doesn't recognize that specific Mime Type.

Clearing your browser cache is always a good idea.

In case it's helpful here's a copy of my /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf file from a server running CentOS 5.9:

```
#        
# PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language which attempts to make it                                             
# easy for developers to write dynamically generated webpages.                                                  
#
<IfModule prefork.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so
</IfModule>

#
# Cause the PHP interpreter to handle files with a .php extension.
#
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php

#
# Add index.php to the list of files that will be served as directory
# indexes.
#
DirectoryIndex index.php

#
# Uncomment the following line to allow PHP to pretty-print .phps
# files as PHP source code:
#
#AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Comment: This is interesting, but in my case, it just outputs the whole PHP script, this time formatted as HTML (as opposed to formatted with ASCII only) — not useful! The problem here is that PHP is not being run correctly somehow, or the wrong headers are being sent...

Comment: Note the last AddType directive (which is commented out in the above example,) causes a .phps file to be pretty-printed in HTML. Is it possible that your Apache configuration is pretty-printing .php files?

Answer (score 7):

If Your .htaccess have anything like this ...
    **AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php .php5 .php4 .php3**
then comment it and try again refreshing this worked for me...

Answer (score 5):

This might be happening due to the missing modules required for your php.
Assuming you have php7 installed, search available php7 modules using

```
sudo apt-cache search php7-*
```

Above command will list all available PHP7 modules for installation.
You can begin installation of modules like,

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-json
```

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. Apache doesn't load php files from a certain website, just downloaded it. I read this post and the answers and I have seen I've got this line into the last place of the .htaccess file:

```
AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php
```

I have commented it and everything works fine.

Thanks to all !!!

Answer (score 3):

After updating PHP to 7.3, PHP scripts where run with *www-data* instead of *$USER* like before.

I needed to reinstall and activate PHP-FPM :

```
sudo apt-get install php-fpm
sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo a2enconf php7.3-fpm
sudo service apache2 restart
```

To ensure everything was ok for **Virtualmin**, i used the *Re-Check Configuration* wizard `/virtual-server/check.cgi`, under *Vitualmin*/*System Settings*.

After that, Apache/PHP was downloading php files instead of running them. So i needed to edit `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.3.conf` to comment the row `SetHandler application/x-httpd-php` like below :

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

After restarting Apache, it solved my issue, hope this help.

Take care of browser cache too.

My system :

```
Ubuntu          16.04.6 LTS
Webmin version      1.932
Usermin version     1.780
Virtualmin version  6.08
Apache version      2.4.41
PHP versions        7.3.12
PHP-FPM         7.3.12 Server
```

Answer (score 2):

I previously has a similar issue, after upgrading from 5.3 to 5.4. But my setup looks a little bit different as that I'm running Debian and using fcgid to server the PHP pages, and not the PHP5 apache/cgi module.
So after I upgraded, it also installed php5_cgi, which collided with my fcgid setup, and would not execute PHP files anymore.

I had to disable the Apache Module and restart Apache

```
a2dismod php5_cgi
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Once the php5_cgi module was out of the way, fcgid was able to serve PHP pages again.

Comment: Aww yeah, this tricky cgi bastard ^^ Solved my problem after updating php from 5.3 to 5.4 too from dotdeb.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar symptoms, yet another solution:
in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf there was a helpful advice in the comment, which I followed:

> ```
> # To re-enable php in user directories comment the following lines
> # (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
> # prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I spent two days tracking this and found out that I was putting my PHP scripts in the wrong directory.

On my standard Ubuntu installation, I was putting the scripts in `/var/www`.  They should have been in `/var/www/html`.

I just started PHP work, so I don't know if my solution relates to the version change you went through.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is using php7 under a Linux environment

Make sure you enable php7

```
sudo a2enmod php7
```

Restart the mysql service and Apache

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok... I know that there are 1.000.000 answers to this questions already, - but I have spent at least 6 effective hours, figuring this one out; and I have googled it hundreds of times and not found a single post about it. So I figured that I would add the solution to my problem here.

### The conclusion

If I commented these two lines out in my .conf-files in the `/etc/apache2/[[SERVER-NAME].conf`-file:

```
php_admin_value engine Off
IPCComTimeout 31
```

I have no idea what they do or how they got there, - but it is in every one of my `.conf`-files. And if I remove those lines and [ensure that there is a symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089525/nginx-sites-enabled-sites-available-cannot-create-soft-link-between-config-fil) in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`-folder, then it doesn't download the index.php - and every works as it should.

### The entire story

I have VirtualMin installed on an Ubuntu 16.04 VPS. I upgraded to PHP version 7.2. Shortly after that, I updated the Ubuntu-version and struck a 'Kernel Offset: Disabled'-error. So I had to go delete the latest Ubuntu-version, - and when my OS booted up again: BOOM! I got the error that his post talks about: For every site on my VPS, it simply downloaded the index.php instead of showing it.

I tried all kinds of stuff:

- Removed PHP7.2 and installed PHP5.6 (I know now, that the PHP-version has nothing to do with it; it's the apache-configuration that needs work).
- Tried enabling and disabling apache modules, on the existing installation, but without luck.
- Then I [removed apache completely](https://askubuntu.com/a/671645/332403) and installed it again, where-after the problem *was still* there!
- Tried playing around with the Virutal Server setup in VirtualMin ( Webmin >> Servers >> Apache Webserver ).
- Checked the configuration on a single Virtual-server ( Virtualmin >> System Settings >> Re-Check Configuration )... This step was pretty nice, since it told which module in Apache was missing; where-after I could enable it with `a2enmod [MODULE_NAME]`. And I found the module name by Googling around. I had to active about 6-8 modules, before I got past that step in the validation - and it took a couple of minutes before the cache ran out, - so doing this was a tedious step.
- And lastly, I figured out above-written conclusion - together with the symlinks, - and then I got it to work. I had to go through it for every site on my VPS, though.

Answer (score 1):

this solved the problem for me (I have php7 installed):

sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0

sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. It turned out that I had both nginx and apache installed and automatically starting on boot. The problem was that nginx was binding to the http port first which prevented apache from starting.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible that you have nginx running but your php is set up to run with apache. To verify, run `service nginx status` and `service apache2 status` to see which is running. In the case that nginx is running and apache is not, just run `sudo service nginx stop; sudo service apache2 start` and your server will now serve php files as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and if you actually never played with your server configuration settings, then your problem is 90% in your **.htaccess** file

You either modify **.htaccess** file LOCALLY, ore delete it (LOCALLY)

Answer (score 1):

If you have virtualmin try to comment out these lines
in your apache configuration in /etc/apache2/sites-available

```
  #RemoveHandler .php
  #RemoveHandler .php7.0
  #php_admin_value engine Off
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to the OP when upgrading php5 from an older version, to 5.5.9, which is the version installed with Mint 17.

I'm running a LAMP setup on a machine on my local network, which I use to preview changes to websites before I upload those changes to the actual live server.  So I maintain a perfect local mirror of the actual site.

After the upgrade, files which run and display perfectly on the actual site would not display, or would only display html on the local machine.  PHP was not parsed.  The phpinfo() command worked, so I knew php was otherwise working. The log generated no errors.  Viewing the page source showed me the actual php code.

I had constructed a test.php page that contained the following code:

`<?php
    phpinfo();
?>`

This worked.  Then I discovered when I changed `<?php` to `<?` the command no longer worked.  All my php sites use `<?` instead of `<?php` which might not be ideal, but it's the reality.  I fixed the problem by going to /etc/php5/apache2 , searching for "short_open_tag" and changing the value from Off to On.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above works,

try commenting out the line

```
SetHandler ....
```

and restart apache using

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

It should work!

Answer (score 0):

PHP56

vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache/libphp5.so
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this kind of problem. This is how I solve it.
After installed **Apache** then I installed **PHP** using this command.

```
sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php
```

it executes correctly but I request **.php** file from Apache, it gives without executing the **PHP** script.

Then I check PHP is enabled.

```
$ cd /etc/apache2
$ ls -l mods-*/*php*
```

but it didn't show any results. I check installed PHP packages.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "
```

Different type of **PHP** versions installed to my computer. Then I remove some **PHP** packages from my previous list, using **apt-get purge**.

```
sudo apt-get purge libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-json
```

I reinstall **PHP**

```
sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql
```

Verify that the PHP module is loaded

```
$ a2query -m php7.0
```

if not enabled with:

```
$ sudo a2enmod php7.0
```

Restart **Apache** server

```
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Finally, I check **PHP** process on **Apache**

create an empty file

```
sudo vim /var/www/html/info.php
```

Add this content to info.php & save.

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

Check on browser:

> http://localhost/info.php

it shows correctly.I think this will help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

When i upgraded from PHP 7.2 to PHP 7.4, i also got same issue. Worked by doing following:-

1. In `[domain].conf file`, commented following:

   ```
   php_admin_value engine Off
   ```

   And Added:

   ```
   AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps
   AddType text/html .php
   ```
2. Disable mod 7.2 and enable 7.4 by following:

   ```
   a2dismod php7.2
   a2enmod php7.4
   ```
3. In `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.4.conf` file, comment following:

   ```
   SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
   php_admin_flag engine Off
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For people who have found this post from Google almost 6 years in the future (and beyond!), you may run into this problem with Apache 2 and PHP 7 while also using the `UserDir` module.

Another possible cause of this problem could be that you are trying to run the script in a "user directory" from the the `UserDir` module.  Running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default.  You will run into this problem if the script is in the `public_html` directory in your home folder and you are trying to access it from `http://localhost/~your_username`.

To fix this, open up `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.2.conf`.  You must comment or delete the tag block at the bottom that reads

```xml
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_flag engine Off
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after using `zypper rm php*` to uninstall PHP and installing it again with `zypper in php7 php7-gd php7-gettext php7-mbstring php7-mysql php7-pear`

I solved it by enabling the apache2 module and restarting the webserver:

```
a2enmod php7 && service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score -1):

If Your .htaccess have anything like this

```
AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtm .html .htm
```

Answer (score -1):

Had numerous attempts fixing my problem realizing the exact same behavior was fixed somehow by clearing my browsers cache. Give it a go.