# php source code displayed instead of pages

Tags: php, apache

I upgraded `php` from `5.3` to `5.5` following this [tutorial](http://phpave.com/upgrade-php-5-3-php-5-5-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) and now when I try to open a php application created with [xataface](http://xataface.com/) by another student on browser I see the `php` source code knowing that it's work well before. I hosted another application that I created with `php 5.5` on the same server (`/var/www/`) the pages are shown without any problem!

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: PHP module either not loaded by Apache or Apache doesn't know to execute `.php*` files with PHP. Hashtag `AddHandler`. This question has been answered 10000 times before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache shows php code instead of executing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache is downloading php files instead of displaying them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them)

Comment: I read the solutions that you propose: for the first I've no httpd.conf, for the second there's no error displayed in my error.log! but why it's work for the second application that I created with php 5.5?

Comment: Are you using <? or <?php at the start of your php files? Maybe your apache is configured not to use short open tags but the php file does use them. That would explain why the other page works, if it uses long open tags.

Comment: does this work <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: yes <?php phpinfo();?> work and show the version of php and other informations

Comment: The problem is solved the problem was this <? it must be <?php, thank you a lot.