# How can I host PHP files on Apache without executing?

Tags: php, apache, http

If I host a PHP file on Apache, it will just be executed. I want clients to be able to download the PHP file without changing the .php extension. I don't want to disable PHP either.

Comment: Try this using [.htaccess][1]. This should help you get the results you want.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18457702/1920638

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to play with apache configuration or .htaccess, then use PHP itself to get it done

create a file `showcode.php` with following code

```
echo file_get_contents('/path/to/your/php/file/having/viewable/code/for/users/');
```