# Facebook realtime update callback url

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to enable real time facebook subscription for my app. This is my PHP code

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET["hub_challenge"])){
    echo $_GET["hub_challenge"];
    return;
}
?>
```

This is just a test code which returns **hub_challenge**. I've uploaded it to my website at http://eno.parseapp.com/fbcb.php

I am trying to subscribe using Facebook's graph explorer. See image below:

[image]

But there is a weird problem. Instead of returning hub_challenge, it's returning the whole php code. Any idea what's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Your php code is being downloaded instead of executed. It's not related to facebook. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Apparently parse does not support php directly. I uploaded this code to my personal domain and it worked.