# HTML POST method downloads the corresponding php

Tags: php, html, post

I am making an authentication form on HTML and trying to link it up with PHP. The **HTML code** is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Authorized logged in</title>
</head>

<div id = "adminBoard">

<form method = "POST" action = "auth.php">
<input type="text" class = "credentialInputL" name="loginInput" value = "login" size = 30>
<input type="password" class = "credentialInputP" name="passwordInput" value = "pass" size = 30>
<input class="loginLogoutButton" type = "submit" value = "Sign in" name="loginLogout">
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The corresponding **auth.php** file (that I made to ensure basic working of POST method before expanding it) is:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['loginInput']) && isset($_POST['passwordInput'])){
        $username = $_POST['loginInput'];
        $password = $_POST['passwordInput'];
        echo "The username is :" . $username;
        echo "The password is :" . $password;
    }
?>
```

But when I open the HTML file in chrome, and click on the Sign in button, then the *auth.php* file simply gets downloaded. No action takes place. Both the html and php files are in the same folder.

Am I missing some syntax / operator / method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them

Comment: Essentially what is happening is the server does not know how to display your php files and is sending them to application/octet-stream. A possible htaccess problem or php problem itself. More information about your server is needed in this specific scenario as this is not code related.

Comment: But I am running it on my localhost, not on Apache or any server!

Comment: This is not coding related. Please see http://serverfault.com/ to address these types of issues

Comment: **But I am running it on my localhost, not on Apache or any server!** you need a server configured to run php, for example, apache.

Comment: "But I am running it on my localhost, not on Apache or any server!" ... well there's your problem...

Comment: Thank you. Now I figure it out :)