# Have trouble installing phpmyadmin on PHP7 Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php-7

I installed PHP7 today with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php-7.0
sudo apt-get install php7.0-cli php7.0-common libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0 php7.0-mysql php7.0-fpm
```

after this, I got 403 forbidden error when I tried to access phpmyadmin.
then I tried to reinstall phpmyadmin with

```
apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

but it still looks for php5 dependencies which arent there anymore:

[image: Image Description]

what can I do to solve this?

Comment: Try to install the latest version manually by donwloading phpmydamin from their webiste. In all fairness, phpmyadmins apt-repo have dependencies to other packages in the official apt-repo. PHP7 doesn't exist in the apt-repo. (you added it manually, which phpmyadmins repo have no clue about).

Comment: Ok I did so and it worked, thanks.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson please post as answer so it's easier to find and take your credit of course.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Install it via wget and create an alias in Apache. Keep track:

Change to directory **/usr/share**:

```
cd /usr/share
```

Change to root user:

```
 sudo su
```

Download phpMyAdmin:

```
wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.5.4.1/phpMyAdmin-4.5.4.1-all-languages.zip
```

Unzip it: (you may install unzip first)

```
unzip phpMyAdmin-4.5.4.1-all-languages.zip
```

Rename the folder:

```
mv phpMyAdmin-4.5.4.1-all-languages phpmyadmin
```

Change permissions:

```
chmod -R 0755 phpmyadmin
```

Configure apache so that it can find it correctly:

```
vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Anywhere after "**DocumentRoot /var/www/html**" insert these line:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/"
<Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/">
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Restart Apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```

And you are ready to go!

Just took a screenshot from my current installation for you to validate it works.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Gilberto Albino, great explanation. I ended up putting the phpmyadmin directory in /var/www/html and creating a virtual host as I have my sites on a VirtualBox VM.

Comment: The solution was tested under Ubuntu running on a VM too.

Comment: I also followed your steps and got the issue resolved. But the folder 'phpmyadmin' is placed inside '/var/www'. I think it's not the proper place to keep it there as other project's files and folders will be there in document root(i.e. /var/www). So I think I shouldn't mix up the those things with phpmyAdmin. Should I delete it as the installation is already done? Or should I move it to some other place? Please guide me in this regard. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't this leave the phpmyadmin zip file in /usr/share? Remove it with this command (first navigate to /usr/share as explained in Gilberto's post if necessary): rm phpMyAdmin-4.5.4.1-all-languages.zip

Comment: you might want to see if there is a newer installation before downloading it, at the time of writing this comment this is the newest one: https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.7.0/phpMyAdmin-4.7.0-all-languages.zip

Answer (score 3):

phpMyAdmin depends on the extension **mbstring**.

For Debian users (tested in Ubuntu 15.10),

```
 sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

For Fedora and CentOS,

```
sudo yum install php70w-mbstring
```

Comment: No package php70w-mbstring available.

Comment: @Jordan, it's a typo. Use: `sudo yum install php70-mbstring`.

Comment: No package php70-mbstring available.

Answer (score 2):

Using git clone of the original repo with a daily update cron job as documented here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/phpmyadmin-with-php7 worked really well for me. I put the following in my Vagrantfile (for a development server)

```
    if [ ! -d /usr/share/phpmyadmin ]; then
        sudo mkdir /usr/share/phpmyadmin
        sudo git clone --depth=1 --branch=STABLE https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin.git /usr/share/phpmyadmin
    fi
```

then added the alias as above

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/"
<Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/">
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and

```
service apache2 restart
```

very easy, only a few steps, always up to date. (Ubuntu wily, php7)

Comment: Hi Steve, I just followed all these steps on my new google compute engine vps that I have just set up and all I am getting is a load of code when I visit ipaddress/phpmyadmin after setting up my 000-default.conf file. Anything else I can do?

Comment: Maybe PHP is not installed correctly? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them

Answer (score 1):

I followed Magnus Eriksson's suggestion from comments

> Try to install the latest version manually by downloading phpmyadmin
>   from their website. In all fairness, phpmyadmins apt-repo has
>   dependencies to other packages in the official apt-repo. PHP7 doesn't
>   exist in the apt-repo. (you added it manually, which phpmyadmins repo
>   has no clue about).

Comment: How did you install that globally? I can only install that by virtual host. I would like to be able to use localhost\phpmyadmin instead of \mysite.pc\phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

Before installing PHP 7 you should backup your database. During the installation process, you will delete your old version of php and be asked if you want to delete your database. Don't do it unless you really want to get rid of it.

Download phpmyadmin from https://www.phpmyadmin.net/ and uncompress it and move the folder to one level below the  document root folder.  It then worked for me when I navigated to it with localhost without further setup.  I had to erase my bookmarks to phpmyadmin and make new bookmarks for the new location. My old database was fine.

I would like to install phpmyadmin globally so it could be installed or reinstalled or updated by apt-get, but don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 7.2, PHP 7, PhpMyadmin 4.6.4

**Step 1:**

```
$ cd /usr/share
$ wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.6.4/phpMyAdmin-4.6.4-all-languages.zip
$ unzip phpMyAdmin-4.6.4-all-languages.zip
$ mv phpMyAdmin-4.6.4-all-languages phpmyadmin
```

**Step 2:**

```
$ cd /etc/httpd/conf.d
$ touch phpmyadmin.conf
$ put on phpmyadmin.conf following content

Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 217.x.x.x
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 217.x.x.x
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/>

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>
```

**Step 3:**

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

**Step 4:** i Cake `http://www.example.com/phpmyadmin`

[image]

[image]