# Need to install 2 dependencies for PHP 7 and PHPMYADMIN Nginx/Ubuntu

Tags: php, apt, dpkg

I've done a ton of searching including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060036/have-trouble-installing-phpmyadmin-on-php7-apache-2-4-7-ubuntu) and even after following the suggestions I'm still get the following error.

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   phpmyadmin : Depends: php-gettext but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: php-seclib but it is not going to be installed

Any suggestions of how to add php-gettext and php-seclib to PHP7?

[Screencapture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H95J.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a problem with PHP7 or any of the other software you're trying to install, but rather appears to be related to the configuration of your package manager.

It appears to be the output of apt and the question you linked to also is about Ubuntu, so all you have to do is either instruct apt/dpkg/aptitude to install dependencies automatically or install them yourself. Assuming you're using a line like `sudo apt-get install php7.0-cli` you just need to add the dependencies to it like `sudo apt-get install php7.0-cli php-seclib php-gettext`.

Comment: I tried installing `php-seclib` and `php-gettext` as you showed in your answer, but I still get the following errors<br>

 php-gettext : Depends: php5 but it is not going to be installed or
                        php5-cli but it is not going to be installed.
 php-seclib : Depends: php5 but it is not going to be installed or
                       php5-cli but it is not going to be installed.
              Recommends: php5-mcrypt but it is not going to be installed or
                          php5-gmp but it is not going to be installed.

Comment: Ah, that actually makes sense but means that, as indicated in the post you linked to, the packages you're trying to install just aren't quite ready to be compatible with each other. You're installing PHP7, but unfortunately the phpMyAdmin package you're installing depends on PHP 5 (indirectly, as it really depends on library packages like `php-seclib` and `php-gettext` which in turn depend on PHP5). So my suggestion, if you really want to run PHP7, is to install phpMyAdmin from the source download at www.phpmyadmin.net -- and if you want a fully packaged version, use the supplied PHP5 version.