# Unable to install gettext on ubuntu php7 server: php_gettext.dll no such file or directory

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, php-extension, circleci

I am trying to install Gettext on a CircleCI build machine (ubuntu 14.4), because my project depends on it.

I am running PHP 7.

I have successfully found the .ini file PHP use, and I have uncommented this line:

```
extension=php_gettext.dll
```

However, then I receive the following warning:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/circleci/php/7.0.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_gettext.dll' - /opt/circleci/php/7.0.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_gettext.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318434/need-to-install-2-dependencies-for-php-7-and-phpmyadmin-nginx-ubuntu is this the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Our (CircleCI) Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't include PHP built with gettext. We have a temp fix over at [Discuss CircleCI](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/ubuntu-14-4-php7-gettext-living-hell/4070) and the next image build should include it by default.

Btw, I'm assuming you are the one who opened that thread? I'm posting here just in case I'm wrong and to help anyone else who might be running into this issue.

-Ricardo
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI