# Call to undefined function __

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to install phpMyAdmin on my Ubuntu server with PHP 7, I already did this guide about installing pMA with PHP 7: [stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060036/have-trouble-installing-phpmyadmin-on-php7-apache-2-4-7-ubuntu)

But when I try to access /phpmyadmin, I get 500 error and I have this log in error log:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function __() in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sanitizing.lib.php:135\nStack trace:\n#0 /usr/share/phpm$

Also I cannot access setup folder nor anything related to pMA, I still get the same thing. I did my research about this problem, but it seems this one is new. What should I do?

Comment: What version of phpMyAdmin are you trying to install

Comment: @RiggsFolly Latest one, 4.6.0, downloaded it from official website itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a same problem, and I solved it :

```
apt install php7.0-mbstring
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Does not work. E: Unable to locate package php7.0-mbstring
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.0-mbstring'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-mbstring

Comment: Should that not be 'apt-get'?

Comment: Should be `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring`. Did the trick for me on Ubuntu.