# phpmyadmin not working for the newest LAMP on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I've installed php 7.2, apache 2.4.27, MySQL 5.6.33 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The problem is that phpmyadmin stopped working. I tried to install the newest version as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060036/have-trouble-installing-phpmyadmin-on-php7-apache-2-4-7-ubuntu), but it didn't help. What is really strange, is that even when I remove all of phpmyadmin related files and directories, I can still access localhost:some_port/phpmyadmin/. I can access this page if phpmyadmin is installed or if it's not. But it doesn't really work, I get to the login page where all the resources are missing (e.g. js, css, images), and when I try to login, I get redirected to http://localhost:some_port/phpmyadmin/php/login.php with a message:

> **Not Found** 
>   The requested resource /phpmyadmin/php/login.php was not found on this server.

I tried removing all files and reinstalling everything related to the whole LAMP stack, but it didn't help.

All I do is run the server on `localhost:8000`, and when I try to access `localhsot:8000/phpmyadmin`, I get

```
Mon Sep 18 01:03:49 2017] 127.0.0.1:43119 [200]: /phpmyadmin/
[Mon Sep 18 01:03:49 2017] 127.0.0.1:43125 [404]: /phpmyadmin/css/bootstrap.min.css - No such file or directory
[Mon Sep 18 01:03:49 2017] 127.0.0.1:43127 [404]: /phpmyadmin/js/propeller.min.js - No such file or directory
[Mon Sep 18 01:03:49 2017] 127.0.0.1:43129 [404]: /phpmyadmin/js/bootstrap.min.js - No such file or directory
[Mon Sep 18 01:03:49 2017] 127.0.0.1:43131 [404]: /phpmyadmin/css/style.css - No such file or directory
[Mon Sep 18 01:03:49 2017] 127.0.0.1:43133 [404]: /phpmyadmin/js/jquery.3.1.1.js - No such file or directory
[Mon Sep 18 01:03:49 2017] 127.0.0.1:43135 [404]: /phpmyadmin/js/app-jquery.js - No such file or directory
[Mon Sep 18 01:03:49 2017] 127.0.0.1:43137 [404]: /phpmyadmin/css/propeller.min.css - No such file or directory
[Mon Sep 18 01:03:49 2017] 127.0.0.1:43139 [404]: /phpmyadmin/img/background/appLogoWhite.png - No such file or directory
[Mon Sep 18 01:03:50 2017] 127.0.0.1:43145 [404]: /phpmyadmin/css/propeller.min.css - No such file or directory
[Mon Sep 18 01:03:50 2017] 127.0.0.1:43147 [404]: /phpmyadmin/css/style.css - No such file or directory
[Mon Sep 18 01:03:50 2017] 127.0.0.1:43149 [404]: /phpmyadmin/js/jquery.3.1.1.js - No such file or directory
[Mon Sep 18 01:03:50 2017] 127.0.0.1:43151 [404]: /phpmyadmin/js/bootstrap.min.js - No such file or directory
[Mon Sep 18 01:03:50 2017] 127.0.0.1:43153 [404]: /phpmyadmin/js/propeller.min.js - No such file or directory
[Mon Sep 18 01:03:50 2017] 127.0.0.1:43155 [404]: /phpmyadmin/js/app-jquery.js - No such file or directory
```

**UPDATE**

OK, now I get

> **phpMyAdmin - Error**
>   The mbstring extension is missing. Please check
>   your PHP configuration.

when accessing http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ (I did get this before but couldn't manage to go beyond this). Then I did

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php-gettext
sudo service apache2 restart
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: Try `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`

Comment: I get 404 response.

Comment: Can you post some code so i see how you are writing the url for the missing assets (js,css)

Comment: Added server console output.

Answer (score 0):

So after the last update, I did

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring
sudo service apache2 restart
```

The problem was that the command

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

installed the mbstring extension for php 7.1.