# some php files keep downloading in WAMPServer

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I downloaded a php system [exam system] and I can't open a specific [configuring database] php file  because it keep asking to download . I read this stack over this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them). I tried it but php module is already active., so what is the additional thing should I do?

Here is my `httpd.conf` file:

[image]

this is the the download dialog appears

[image]

I hosted it and it works the problem exist only in local/wamp server.

I'm messing with this about 2 days. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the PHP module loaded?

Comment: Btw, you can copy text from the editor and paste it directly in the question, no need for screenshots of text ...

Comment: @GeraldSchneider sorry i thought if it's uncommented then that module is loaded

Comment: @GeraldSchneider this the loaded extensions .http://i.imgur.com/nXRoME3.png

Comment: You should not have a `httpd.conf` in your project file. I assume this is there for reference so you can check that your real `httpd.conf` file has all the correct settings and should then be removed. Read the installation instructions again!

Comment: @RiggsFolly  yes in project folder there is a httpd file .and in apache there i a another one right?so above preview is file of apache .the content of httpd in project file is this `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
 #Use PHP 5.4
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
Options -Indexes`

Comment: @RiggsFolly wamp server show my php version is 5.5 .so do i change it to 5.4 ?? i'm so confused.also note that i hosted it in free server and it works it shows page.the problem exist in localhost .

Comment: What version of WAMPServer did you install? And what version of PHP does it contain?

Comment: @RiggsFolly wamp 2.5 and php 5.5.12 . i didn't do anything when i host it in free live server .but it works

Answer (score 2):

Your are using same handler multiple times in httpd.conf, merge those:

Only put this line related to **.php** extension, comment rest of the lines & try again after restarting web server:

```
Addhandler application/x-httpd-php .php .php3
```

Comment: ok i will try and tell u

Comment: in my project folder there is a .httpd file write by author of this project. it contain this `Use PHP 5.4
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
Options -Indexes`  

so should i do specific thing ??

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

*the content of httpd in project file is this*

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] 
#Use PHP 5.4 AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php 
Options -Indexes
```

This is actually what you would expect to see in a `.htaccess` file.

So try changing the filename from `httpd.conf` to `.htaccess` (the leading dot is imporant)

Comment: but .htaccess file already exist in the project folder.

Comment: Where did you download this  project from?

Comment: here http://codecanyon.net/item/digi-online-examination-system-does/full_screen_preview/8610180

Comment: http://simultase.esy.es/myproject/install/ here i hosted it .you can see it shows php page without anyproblem

Comment: So what do you do to cause this download to start?

Comment: i don't know .i'm so confused

Comment: Does this happen as part of the install process, or just when using the site normally

Comment: it happens on every php file in that project folders but not in other projects

Comment: Last suggestion. Create a Virtual Host to run this site in. [Here is how to do it, if you dont already know](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Comment: hello it suddenly start working .i didn't create vertual host either .i just re extract files .should i delete the question??thanks your help too much

Comment: I guess so, it must have been a woops in the extract.