# Openshift DIY cartridge site is downloading php files instead of running them

Tags: php, .htaccess, openshift

I have an openshift app with diy cartridge where I have a bunch of `php` and `html` files in the `$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/diy` folder. The `html` files in this folder are displayed properly on the browser. However, the `php` ones are just downloaded to the browser instead of being executed.

Are `php` files not allowed to be run in a `diy` cartridge or am I doing something wrong? The `.openshift` folder is empty, except for a `cron` folder (I've added a cron cartridge to my app too).

I've also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them) question, but the `.htaccess` workaround doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you would like to have the PHP interpreter on your DIY cartridge. You can inspire for example [here](https://github.com/elkuku/openshift-diy-php), on how to install Apache with PHP on a DIY cartridge. [Here](https://github.com/boekkooi/openshift-diy-nginx-php) you can find another avenue using nginx.

Comment: Thanks, @Jiri Fiala! However, I found that just dropping the existing app and recreating a new `php` app was a much easier and faster solution in my current situation.

Comment: That sure makes sense and is the most straightforward solution, if you need just the PHP. (I thought you had something else on the DIY cartridge).

Comment: Actually I did have some obsolete `python` scripts on that app before, and the `php` came as a new requirement. I thought rather than creating a new php app, why not reuse that old one since I no longer needed that. However, deleting the old apps and creating new ones seem to be the easier way to go!