# phpinfo.php downloading instead of viewing

Tags: apache, php

I just set up my DigitalOcean server and installed apache. I created a phpinfo.php file to check to see if everything had installed correctly, however my I go to my server link it just downloads the .php file instead of viewing it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

this is what I put in the file

```
<?php phpinfo();?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache is downloading php files instead of displaying them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them)