# PHP file downloading instead of displaying files

Tags: php, apache

I have looked at many answers online and none of them have worked. I have a .php file with some html in it that runs perfectly on localhost, but when I run it from the website I want to actually have it on, it downloads the file instead of displaying it. I have tried changing my httpd.conf file to include the lines

```
AddType  application/x-httpd-php         .php
AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps

LoadModule php5_module        modules/mod_php55.so
```

but that still didn't change anything.

I am using XAMPP and the download included php so I don't think it is an issue of not having that installed. I am using OS X (El Capitan) if that makes a difference or helps anyone come up with a solution.

Links I've been to as of now:

[Apache is downloading php files instead of displaying them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/447675/index-php-is-downloading-instead-of-displaying
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2220415

Comment: is that .so file actually in the modules dir? is it compiled for your version of apache? did you check if it really loaded?

Comment: @MarcB I just looked in the modules directory and found out that it isn't there. There is a libphp5.so file in there though. I'm pretty new to apache so I will have to look into downloading mod_php55.so