# Apache not serving PHP files but server html

Tags: php, apache, bitnami

This is very strange, all of the sudden apache is not serving .php file format. It goes into a continuos loading loop in a browser, and when checked in logs i can see 408 status for all php requests.

Any reason what caused this issue.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/334269/apache-doesnt-serve-files-to-be-interpreted-by-the-browser-but-to-be-downloaded    and       http://serverfault.com/questions/165970/apache-localhost-serving-index-html-but-not-serving-php-files   and       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them

Comment: Solved it. Had to restart the PHP FPM