# Ubuntu 12.04 Apache2 download php file instead of execute

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu 12.04. 
I downlod a Apache2 2.4 version and Php 5.4 version.

Then i tried to run simple php file like :

phpinfo.php

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

But apache2 download this file into my local instead of execute.

I am researching on google and they suggested to install `libapache2-mod-php5`

I tried to install this, but error occured. It wants to Php 5.3 version and Apache2 2.2 version:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libapache2-mod-php5 :
>   Depends: apache2.2-common but it is not going to be installed
>                          Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.21) but 5.4.45-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1 is to be installed

But i have to create owncloud on my machine and owncloud requires php 5.4 version, the link is here :
https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/14363

So how can i run php files on apache2 2.4 with ubuntu 12.04 version ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them