# Apache downloading php file

Tags: php, apache, linode, roundcube

I think I'm having the same issue as this link: [Apache is downloading php files instead of displaying them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them)

I'm trying to install Roundcube on my Linode server but when I go to www.myurl.com/roundcube it downloads the php files.

I read through that link and I see people saying to add things to different files, but I don't know where to look.

I'm new to Linode, I'm used to hosts with cPanels and such. So, I need a bit of a point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

With linode you have the raw server ie you need to ssh into it and configure it. Start with this guide.

https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/hosting-a-website

Once you have a basic site running then configure apache to use PHP.