# When I try to open my Wordpress page, that automatically download instead to be open

Tags: wordpress

Until today I can open my Wp page, but today instead of open, it's just automatically get started to download. If you have any idea why, please help me.

This is my site: http://marketingfokusz.hu/

This is what in the htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Did you change any sort of configuration in Apache today? (httpd.conf file)

Comment: no,i do not change anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache is downloading php files instead of displaying them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them)

Comment: Try the solution in this other question and come back and tell us if it worked.