# PHP files not running in firefox

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04

Firefox only asks me to download the file's source. View-source shows me source code.

a2enmod php7.0

```
Considering conflict php5 for php7.0:
Module php7.0 already enabled
```

php -v

`PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies`

Comment: Also, I have restarted the server several times using `service apache2 restart`

Comment: Does this *only* happen in Firefox? Because that seems very unlikely.

Comment: It is because you have installed PHP CLI only, you need to install it properly.

Comment: Hello i find two link that might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them http://serverfault.com/questions/25227/why-is-php-script-downloaded-instead-of-executed

Comment: This is most likely because of your server not PHP, are you using Apache or nginx?

Comment: I am using Apache @Andy

Comment: This happens both in Firefox and Google chrome @Matt

Comment: I think I will just purge and reinstall.. I guess

Comment: @RosieRed it's usually because apache is serving the PHP files and not passing them onto PHP-FPM - Try this https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/apache-with-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend a full installation in case you intend to develop something.

Example: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (xenial)

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-odbc php7.0-pgsql php7.0-sqlite3 php7.0-mysql php7.0-fpm php7.0-curl php7.0-intl php7.0-gd php7.0-mysql php7.0-bz2 php7.0-zip php7.0-gmp php7.0-json php7.0-xsl php7.0-tidy php7.0-xmlrp php7.0-readline php7.0-mbstring php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-recode php7.0-pspell php7.0-dev php-gettext libapache2-mod-php7.0
```