# why a file php will be downloaded after each calling with argument

Tags: javascript, php, html

when the link http://127.0.0.1:8080/example.php?id=38 will be executed I can't see the content of this page php... chrome will download this file !!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>test</title>
       
        <script src="public/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php
     // check the input
            //is_numeric($_GET['id']) or die("invalid URL");
           
  ?>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     console.log(<?php $_GET['id'] ?>);
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Seems like your html above is incomplete? You're at least missing the <form> tag.

Comment: same problem without form !

Comment: So when you're trying to access this page, it's being downloaded directly instead of the PHP engine being activated? My best guess is that your web server is not configured correctly to trigger the PHP server. Are you using the built-in web server in PHP, or something else like Apache or nginx?

Comment: yes I'm using Apache v 2.4.23

Comment: Is it Laravel Project?

Comment: no Im using angularJS just i want to open the content of this file in modal

Comment: If it's trying to download the file it's because the server doesn't know how to handle php extensions, you'll  need to ensure you have .php as a type and also that php module is loaded in the apache config file. I presume your HTML files all work ok?

Answer (score 0):

This is normally due to an improper handler code. In the .htaccess file, you will want to ensure the handler code matches your version of php. If it does not, the php files may try to download instead of process.

To use the default php version on the server, use the following code:

## Use system PHP5 as default

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php

You may also specify different php versions, depending on your need:

## Use system PHP5.2 as default

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php

## Use system PHP5.3 as default

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53.php

## Use system PHP5.4 as default

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

## Use system PHP5.5 as default

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php

Also try:

The correct AddType for php is application/x-httpd-php

```
AddType  application/x-httpd-php         .php
AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps
```

Also make sure your php module is loaded

```
LoadModule php5_module        modules/mod_php55.so
```

When you're configuring apache then try to view the page from another browser - I've had days when chrome stubbornly caches the result and it keeps downloading the source code while in another browser it's just fine.
Refer for more - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them)

Comment: same problem even without the console.log !