# Apache2 server file getting downloaded instead of giving output

Tags: php, html, apache

I am using Apache2 server and i have created these two files as below:

```
/var/www/html/Roshan/web.html

/var/www/html/Roshan/cgi/mypage.php
```

But instead of getting output on clicking `submit` button, file `mypage.php` is getting downloaded.
How can i fix this problem?

I got this answer for same question asked by someone else but i am not getting this file `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

Uncommenting the following line in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` fixed the problem for me:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Comment: `Uncommenting the following line in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf fixed the problem for me:`
What is the problem then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache is downloading php files instead of displaying them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them)

Comment: " i am not getting this file /etc/apache2/httpd.conf" — Then you config file is somewhere else. We don't know where your particular build is set to look for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing a mistake of running the web.html file by double clicking on it or by entering this:

file:///var/www/html/Roshan/web.html

in my web browser which is a wrong way because by this way my html code was not running in Apache 2 server.
so the correct method is start the browser and type :

http://localhost/Roshan/web.html

this will correctly start the Apache 2 server and file will be executed instead of getting downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu don't have **httpd.conf** by default and you must change `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. So add following line to **apache2.conf** and **restart apache**:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Note: Move your php file in ***/var/www/html/Roshan/mypage.php***. Cgi folder running cgi scripts and not running php scripts.

Comment: yes i also tried moving php file but still it is getting downloaded.

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: For ubuntu, you can change `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Comment: yes now i have added above line in apache2.conf but still it is getting downloaded.

Comment: Are you restart apache? Restart required when change apache config.

Comment: yes i restarted my problem is solved, problem was something else see above i have answered it. Still thank you for your help.