# Browser treating link as download, should be page hyperlink

Tags: html, browser, hyperlink, download

This is driving me crazy. I can't see the logic in to why this is happening and not even really sure how to search for the issue.

I have a menu with links to pages. Suddenly for no reason, my browsers is downloading some menu links as if it was a file link. I've tried reordering the pages in the CMS and changing the page url but it still happens. Its fine on my local machine dev site.
I get this error: **"Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted"**
Which others have had but refers to file links, which mine is not.

[Website here](http://www.legacyandart.com)

Just hit Menu at the top > Collections > Automotive

If this loads for you try using the Menu again to choose a different catalogue and it should re create the error above.

Comment: Bizarre. What is the mime type of the link? Perhaps your settings has set the type to application/octet-stream

Comment: Refer this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them

Answer (score 0):

In the end I talked to the hosting company who said:
**"I’ve adjusted the openbasedir settings so that you can open files outside of the directories which domains are restricted to as standard."**
This has revolved the issue.