# PHP/apache not working on localhost Fedora 26

Tags: php, apache, fedora, httpd.conf

I've been trying to get PHP working locally on my machine in Fedora 26.

I have httpd installed, and that seems to be working. When I first had it set up, typing localhost in my browser showed me the HTML contents `/var/www/html/index.html`, but not the PHP contents. `<?php  phpinfo(); ?>` was not working, either.

I think PHP is also working, since `php -r "phpinfo();"` works in the command line.

I tried following the advice [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them) by adding `AddType  application/x-httpd-php .php` to my httpd.conf file, and this made my browser try to download the PHP files instead of displaying them. Weirdly, when I took this line back out and restarted httpd, my browser is still trying to download the files.

Comment: What error did you get on your browser?

Comment: @Yahya No error, it's just trying to download the PHP file instead of displaying it. Before it was not displaying PHP at all. Same thing across multiple browsers.

Comment: Do you load php module in apache configurations?

Comment: I didn't realize I needed to do that manually. I just tried adding `LoadModule php7_module modules/mod_php.so` to the httpd.conf file, but then Apache failed to start because `/etc/httpd/modules/mod_php.so` is missing. 

This distro already had PHP, but I had to install httpd. Should I try to reinstall PHP so it works with apache?

Comment: So you should install `mod_php`

Comment: @Yahya I reinstalled PHP, but it did not add a `mod_php.so` file.

Comment: It's a module, and it's not install with php itself.

Comment: @Yahya running `dnf install mod_php` says it's already installed? `Package php-7.1.11-1.fc26.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.`, but there is no mod_php.so file still

Comment: @Yahya Aha! The file isn't called `mod_php.so`, because I guess that would be too obvious. It's called `libphp7.so`. So manually loading that module does fix all my problems. PHP is now being displayed correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't good to sum up all this to an answer? If you ok with that, let me do it?!

Comment: @Yahya Yeah, thanks for your help. If you want to summarize it as an answer, I will checkmark it. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them) is good, except for that the `LoadModule` line should reference `libphp7.0.so` instead of `mod_php55.so` which I did not realize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all add php AddType to to `httpd.conf` file:

```
AddType  application/x-httpd-php         .php
AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps
```

And then load php module in apache configuration based on your php version that installed on your machine and you wanted to use:

```
LoadModule php7_module        modules/libphp7.0.so
```