# Use php site with socket.io chat application

Tags: php, html, websocket, server, socket.io

I have created a basic chat application using the walk through on socket.io

I have added further content to the application, including database info, which meant I had to change the index.html to index.php.

Now when I try and run the application, it just downloads a document with all the code for the page, and it does not run.

I have changed all the code to index.php where necessary.

If I change the file name back to index.html and change the relevant code, it then works fine....

I really need to have database info on the page, which is why it needs to be index.php

Does anyone know why it does this? Is there a work around?

Comment: Seems like a server configuration problem.

Comment: Maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them