# server downloading index.php instead of execution laravel

Tags: php, laravel

after one month of deploy my site in host and working normally. 
now i can't access in any page i get download index.php ??
why and how i can fix that ?

> index.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';


$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';


$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them) Maybe some server confs were changed?

Comment: Usually happens if php is not configured properly. You are running "php artisan serve" right?

Comment: You webserver won't execute php, therefore fall back to offer the file for download. Thats not a PHP nor laravel issue, but a hosting issue. What webserver do you use and how is it configured to execute PHP scripts?

Comment: no i don't run the server ,because the server was working normal all time ,i will contact my support

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache is downloading php files instead of displaying them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them)

Answer (score 0):

Check this 2 things.

1. You have php installed on your server, php -v on the terminal
2. The directory index for the web-server ex apache this can be on the main configuration or in a virtual host.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```