# Server sub domain downloading index.php instead of executing

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu-16.04, virtualmin

I deployed my laravel app to the server sub domain and set the document root to point to public, when I entered the url it downloads the index.php file instead of executing, but I am successfully running another laravel application on another sub domain on the same server.

I have tried adding the following code to my `.htaccess` file to no avail

```
AddType  application/x-httpd-php         .php
AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps
```

Comment: You have to enable PHP in your server configuration. Do you use Apache or Nginx?

Comment: Apache , when i type php -v it gives me a response of 7.2

Comment: _“when i type php -v”_ … then you are working on the _command line_, which has little to do with the web server to begin with.

Comment: Check out this post, might be same problem + solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them