# GULP 4 - Using browsersync with PHP prompts for download

Tags: php, gulp

I'm new to Gulp so please be kind.
In my gulpfile.js I'm using this configuration for BrowserSync and gulp-connect-php server:

```
    phpConnect.server({}, function (){
        browserSync.init({
            server:{ 
                proxy: "localhost:3000",
                baseDir:"./build/",
                index: "index.php",
                //directory: true
            }
        }); 
    });
```

Every time I start my tasks with `gulp dev`, which is my default task, everything works except that when I open the browser to localhost:3000 a download is prompted for

> application/x-httpd-php (2,5 kB)

I've tried to read the other answers here on Stackoverflow and on Github. I've no idea what to do to fix this. 
I'm working on a MacBookAir 2017, Catalina updated regularly.
I'm using Homebrew for Apache, Firefox and php7.

**EDIT**

After the first answer I think the problem is actually with mime.types. I've added them to my configuration file but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I really am a noob when it comes to Gulp and BrowserSync.
The correct configuration is:

```
    gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
    phpConnect.server({
        base:'./build/',
        hostname:'127.0.0.1'
    }, function (){
        browserSync.init({
            proxy: "127.0.0.1:8000"
        }); 
    });
});
```

because I'm trying to use the PHP Development Server on port 8000 and BrowserSync as PROXY not as a SERVER. Dumb me. 
I hope this will save some time to someone in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should checkk in

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

file:

```
AddType  application/x-httpd-php         .php
AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps
```

Or something similar and: (for PHP 7 example)

```
LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
```

[Apache is downloading php files instead of displaying them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them)

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My configuration file for apache is actually located in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf because I'm using MacOS and Homebrew. I tried following the instructions in the link you provided and still no luck. But at least as far as I understand now  this is a problem with mime types not working as they should.

Comment: Ah I see, too bad it did not work. Hope you can figure it out