# PHP file gets downloaded instead of being executed

Tags: php, xampp

I created a php file and saved it in the htdocs folder inside Xampp folder in C.(I am using XAMPP as the web server) So when I type localhost and try to open that php file in the web browser, it gets downloaded instead of being executed. Why is that?

I don't know what to do.

Comment: What is the filename?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache is downloading php files instead of displaying them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them)

Comment: It is just index.php